# Using kafka-preferred-replica-election with correct flags

Tags: apache-kafka

we have Kafka HDP cluster with version 1.0

we want to use the `kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh` , in order to replace the leader ID with other leader ID , and as results of -1 on that leader example:

```
Topic: topic_test     Partition: 0    Leader: -1      Replicas: 1006  Isr: 1006
```

but we get the following exceptions

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh --zookeeper zookeeper01:2181 --topic topic_test  --partition 0  --election-type preferred


GC log rotation is turned off
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: topic is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at kafka.admin.PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionCommand$.main(PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionCommand.scala:49)
        at kafka.admin.PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionCommand.main(PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionCommand.scala
```

)

also we try with

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh --bootstrap-server kafka01:9092 --topic topic_test  --partition 0  --election-type preferred


To enable GC log rotation, use -Xloggc:<filename> -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=<num_of_files>
where num_of_file > 0
GC log rotation is turned off
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: bootstrap-server is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at kafka.admin.PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionCommand$.main(PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionCommand.scala:49)
        at kafka.admin.PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionCommand.main(PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionCommand.scala)
```

what is wrong with our Kafka cli?

reference - https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-demo-using-kafka-leader-election.html

Comment: 1) `bootstrap-server` wasn't added until newer versions of Kafka, and could be `bootstrap.servers` and you're not reading official documentation, so there could be typos 2) Run the command with no options. It'll tell you all the supported flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official wiki page says you need a json file, not a topic flag, and not bootstrap server flag

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=31819985#Replicationtools-1.PreferredReplicaLeaderElectionTool